# Sonar 4.1.1 maven plugin can't be resolved

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 4.1.1 and have the following configuration in my pom.xml file:

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>4.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

When I try to run sonar from the command line using the maven plugin I get:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:4.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:4.1.1: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:4.1.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Do I need to make some configuration changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this configuration is not needed. Have you try to run an analysis without it? You should give a try if you haven't.
But if you really need to force the version of the sonar-maven-plugin, you should set it to 2.1 on Maven 3.
See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven for more details.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mvn clean sonar:sonar -U
```

The `-U` flag means force update of dependencies.

Comment: Well, try remove local repository(defaults to $HOME/.m2/repository) and try the same command again.

Comment: I've done that and it still can't pick up the dependencies. I even installed the plugin jars into my local repository, yet I still get the same error. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @Zak, could you show me the result of `mvn clean sonar:sonar -U -cpu -X`?

Comment: I switched to version 2.1 of the sonar-maven-plugin and everything now works perfectly. I'm noticing that the correct version of the plugin (4.1.1) is being downloaded and run even though I specified version 2.1.